# Android gridView with Constant first item

Tags: android, gridview

Initially i start my screen with gridview with one item. click on the item will take me to another screen where i enter image and title and press ok will come to the first screen where the grid view is update , but i wan the first item to stay even after entering many items.

Tried with below adapter but it is not working

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = items;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.addcompany_layout,null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }



        if(position!=0){
            RowItem rowItem = rowItems.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(context, rowItem.getCompany_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getCompany_name());
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(rowItem.getImagepath()));
        }



                return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted I don't see any method to update your adapter. So it boils down to what you pass into constructor.

If you don't want to manage this outside of your adapter class, you can create your first RowItem in constructor, put it on the first position, then populate the rest.

```
public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
    this.context = context;
    // Construct your first item
    // Alternatively you can pass it as a param
    this.firstItem = new RowItem(); 

    this.rowItems = items;
    this.rowItems.add(0, firstItem);
}
```